# Limesurvey inline pictures

Tags: email, html-email, phpmailer, swiftmailer, limesurvey

Outlook keeps blocking images within Limesurvey invite mails, since their not attached.

It uses PhpMailer, although this script has the feature "AddEmbeddedImage" built in, the links to the images remain direct (hxxp://www..../xxx.jpg), and not replaced with CID Links.

PhpMAiler's latest version doesn't help either... Limesurvey has it integrated as a third party folder.

Anyone please know how to fix this issue, or know to switch completeley to SwiftMailer, I've came across many publications and it seems to be more efficient.

Massive thanks in advance.

Comment: Outlook blocks images by default on loading the email. Do they show when you enable them? Also, are your image links `http://` or `hxxp://` as you have it in your question?

Comment: Hi John, Thanks a lot for your response. Yes the images show once I eanable them. image links are http, just replaxed so it want be active.